# Capacitive load of PSU

Tags: power-supply, capacitive

I see many power supplies have a parameter called max capacitive load. In this case for the below PSU, it is 2200uF.

What does this mean exactly?

I cannot measure the capacitance of the load easily so how do I know if this power supply will work for me?

If I exceed the 2200uF what will happen?

Website:

https://recom-power.com/en/products/dc-dc-converters/dc-dc-unregulated/rec-s-R1SX.html?0

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does [max capacitive load] mean exactly?

This is the maximum amount of capacitance than can be directly connected to it's output.

> If I exceed the [max capacitive load] what will happen?

In general, the regulator can become unstable.  It may lose regulation (voltage setpoint) or even oscillate wildly.  This is seldom good for the downstream circuitry, so is to be avoided.

This happens because the regulator is a switching type.  It only knows *when* to switch by looking at the output and doing some math on the tiny ripples seen there.  The addition of too much capacitance delays those ripples enough that the math no longer works, leading to erratic operation.

> I cannot measure the capacitance, so how do I know if this power supply will work?

This supply is assuming that *you* are building the load also, so will know what the connected capacitance is.

If you didn't build the load, but can examine the board, you can likely estimate the capacitance by adding up the values of all the caps.  This may be easy for some boards (like a small trinket) with few components, or quite involved for something bigger with many parts on it.  Some parts are misleading too; two surface-mount caps can look identical but one is 2.2µF and the other is 100µF.

If you can't examine the load, then one thing you might be able to do is add a known value of series resistance to it's input (say 10Ω), and power it from a beefy bench supply.  This is using the [tau time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant) concept.  Use an oscilloscope to measure the voltage across the load, and catch a waveform as it "ramps up" to max of say, 5V.  When it reaches 63.2% of the max (5V*0.632 = 3.16V), count how much time has elapsed from zero.  Say this is 0.01s or 10ms.  Then plug in the values:

$$\tau = R\cdot C$$
$$0.01s = 10Ω\cdot C$$
$$\require{cancel}\frac{0.01s}{10Ω} = \frac{\bcancel{10Ω}\cdot C}{\bcancel{10Ω}}$$
$$0.001 = C$$

Now note this is 0.001 *Farads*... in [engineering units](https://www.theiet.org/media/4173/units-and-symbols.pdf) this would be 1mF or 1,000µF... so this particular load should be ok if 2,200µF is the limit.

Note that this *won't work* for some types of circuits, like other switching supplies or circuits that monitor voltage and only "come on" when a certain threshold is exceeded.  But it's quick and easy to test, so could be better than guessing.

Answer (score 6):

Many power supplies can not continously deliver the maximum current at a much lower output voltage than specified. A capacitive load initially is a short circuit and the supply needs time to charge it. This is a transient state with potentially bad efficiency and therefore an internal timeout can be bound to it.

Some supplies enter a "hiccup mode", periodically retrying the start, others implement a current foldback. In these cases the voltage will not come up with this reduced current because the capacitor is not the only load.

Many AC line SMPS circuits need internal power provided by an auxiliary winding of the transformer. To start at all, a capacitor is charged with a small current and this energy is just sufficient for a short period. If the transformers secondary side cannot reach the target voltage in time, the internal supply fails as well.